# Caesar Shift Decoder in python

Tags: python, encryption, brute-force, caesar-cipher

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. The shift works flawlessly excpet for it skips the first letter in the cipher code. What gives? It should translate to WELCOMETOCRYPTOGRAPHY but does ELCOME....

```
    cipher = 'ZGXJHZOJXMTKOJBMVKCT'
    letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

    plain = ""
    for x in cipher:
            if x in letters:
                    pos = (letters.find(x) - 21) % 26
            plain += letters[pos]
    print ("Key #%s: %s") % (c, plain)
```

Comment: Are you sure your cipher is right? Because `WELCOMETOCRYPTOGRAPHY` has 21 characters, and `ZGXJHZOJXMTKOJBMVKCT` only has 20.

Comment: Your code is correct. Your input is wrong, you wanted to input `'RZGXJHZOJXMTKOJBMVKCT'`

Answer (score -1):

Your code is fine.  Your cipher itself is missing the first letter.
The cipher should look like `RZGXJHZOJXMTKOJBMVKCT` not `ZGXJHZOJXMTKOJBMVKCT`